# Hide form control when clicking outside its boundaries, VBA Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with the following controls:

1. Three Text Boxes (text_box_a, text_box_b, text_box_c)
2. List Box (list_ctrl)
3. Picture Frame (pic_frame)

I would like for the list box to disappear whenever the user clicks outside its boundaries but not when it clicks one specific text box (**text_box_a**). Also for it to reappear when it clicks inside said text box.

What I've tried:

```
Private Sub text_box_a_GotFocus()
    Me.list_ctrl.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub list_ctrl_LostFocus()
    If Not (Me.text_box_a Is Me.ActiveControl) Then
        Me.list_ctrl.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm working in Microsoft Access 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use 2 standard functions in your code (one to hide the control, the other to show it), and then assign your text-box `OnGotFocus` events to one depending on whether it's `text_box_a` or one of the other controls:

First, you set up the 2 different functions:

```
Public Function ShowListBox()
    Me.list_ctrl.Visible = True
End Function

Public Function HideListBox()        
    ' if active control is list box, change active control
    ' before hiding list box
    If Me.ActiveControl.Name = Me.list_ctrl.Name Then
        Me.text_box_b.SetFocus
    End If

    Me.list_ctrl.Visible = False

End Function
```

Then, you can assign the different control events to one of these in a loop in the `FormLoad` event. Something like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    ' set up the form detail's OnClick event separately from the control loop.
    Me.Detail.OnClick = "=HideListBox()"

    Dim ctl As Access.Control

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If ctl.Name = Me.list_ctrl.Name Then
            ' do nothing here
            ' (control will be hidden or not
            ' based on other control's OnGotFocus,
            ' or Form details OnClick
        ElseIf ctl.Name = Me.text_box_a.Name Then
            ctl.OnGotFocus = "=ShowListBox()"
        ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Then
            ctl.OnGotFocus = "=HideListBox()"
        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub
```

Comment: It triggered an error: "Object doesn't support this property or method" regarding the OnGotFocus property. It also didn't appear in the suggestions list. I suppose it might be a relatively new thing. I'm working in ms-access 2013

Also. Will this work continuously? Wouldn't this work only at the start of the UI?

Comment: This one ctl.OnGotFocus = "=ShowListBox()"

Comment: @Juan: Add a breakpoint right before that line, and then make sure that the `ctl` in question is your `text_box_a` (and that it is, in fact, a text box).

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I modified the code for it to work on every Control besides text boxes. It was ctl.OnGotFocus = "=HideListBox()" where i was getting the error not the other one. Turns out, imgControls and labels dont have OnGotFocus properties, so i just replaced it with OnClick and it worked perfectly. Do you think i should keep using OnClick? Or is that not advised?

Comment: @JuanPerez: `OnEnter` or `OnGotFocus` should both work. The `OnClick` event might be problematic, if you have users that use the keyboard to navigate the form (e.g. by using Tab). As @UnhandledException noted, you can use `OnEnter` instead of `OnGotFocus`.

Comment: Thanks. I added a case just for labels and Images using OnClick. As for TextBoxes, i kept them with OnEnter and it worked

Answer (score 1):

> > I would like for the list box to disappear whenever the user clicks outside its boundaries...

If you mean that you click in the forms detail section, by saying 'outside its boundaries', then you can use the `Detail_Click()` event of the form.

Using the `Enter` event of the textboxes also 'catches' the clicks on the corresponding labels and also work when you use the keyboard to move the focus.

```
Private Sub Detail_Click()
    If Not (Me.list_ctrl Is Me.ActiveControl) Then
        Me.list_ctrl.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub text_box_a_Enter()
    Me.list_ctrl.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub text_box_b_Enter()
    Me.list_ctrl.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub text_box_c_Click()
    Me.list_ctrl.Visible = True
End Sub
```

But there is a problem in hiding the `list_ctrl` when it has the focus.

Comment: This works, however I'd have to manually add an event for each exception  if i want to add more controls in the future. Is there a cleaner way to go about doing this?

Comment: Please give me an example of 'each expection' and 'more controls'.

Comment: Let's say i add more text boxes, each one has a label. Detail_Click() won't trigger when i click on the labels (i've tested this). So i'd have add an click event to hide the list for each label

Comment: I think there is no such easy way, because Microsoft Access has no event-bubbling. You can't catch an event of a control in a common form event. And a label also has no event at all.

Comment: You could use the `Enter` event of a textBox instead of the `Click` event to also catch clicks on the corresponding label. I edited my answer.